# Exploding a full string without a delimiter in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, output, explode

If I got a string like `BA00008424BA00008425BA00008426`. How can I explode these into:

```
['BA00008424', 'BA00008425', 'BA00008426']
```

From this example..

```
$pizza = "piece1|piece2|piece3|piece4|piece5|piece6";

$pieces = explode("|", $pizza);
```

Here they explode with "**|**" but I want to explode before each "**BA**".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace the `BA` with `BA[space]` and then explode it with space as the delimiter, and grab all the elements except the first one as it contains a space:

```
$str = 'BA00008424BA00008425BA00008426';
$str = str_replace('BA', ' BA', $str);
print_r(array_slice(explode(' ', $str), 1));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => BA00008424
    [1] => BA00008425
    [2] => BA00008426
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/133119)

Comment: This s right method....the problem with str_split is  if the count is more than 10 then it will be problem....so this way is recommended

Comment: It will just count 3 BA's so it's great for me. Thanks man! :)

Answer (score 9):

If `BA***` are always the same length, you can try with [str_split](http://php.net/str_split). Otherwise you can explode by "BA" and add BA to the exploded pieces.

Comment: No, BA is not always the same length. How do I explode by "BA"?

Comment: @Treps: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22908343/1438393). That does exactly what you want.

Comment: How do you explode by "|"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use str_split, if the numbers are always of a fixed length.

```
$str = "BA00008424BA00008425BA00008426";
$output = str_split($str, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_match_all

```
<?php
 $str="BA00008424BA00008425BA00008426";
$data=array();
 preg_match_all('/\w{2}\d{8}/', $str, $data);
 print_r($data);
// OUTPUT- Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => BA00008424 [1] => BA00008425 [2] => BA00008426 ) )
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can replace this value for space after explode

See Below Example :

```
$str = "BA00008424BA00008425BA00008426";
$str = str_replace('BA', ',BA', $str);
print_r(array_slice(explode(',', $str), 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

$arr2 = str_split($str, 10);

Will do the trick If it is always ten long

Answer (score 0):

Are all the codes the same length? In that case you could use:

```
$str = 'BA00008424BA00008425BA00008426';
var_dump(str_split($str, 10));
```

In case they do not have the same length, you could preg match them, but I'd rather save the input value in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Obligatory regex version. Although I really like Shankar's 'insert space' answer, and regexes can be slow.

That said, given you have a clear pattern (two char prefix followed by digits) I think it's a worthwhile alternative:

```
<?php

$subject = 'BA00008424BA00008425BA00008426';
$pattern = '/BA\d+/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => BA00008424
            [1] => BA00008425
            [2] => BA00008426
        )

)
```

Example here: https://eval.in/133117

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

If segments have an unknown length but always start with non-digits, then split between digits and non-digits:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/mZFaI))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/\d+\K(?=\D)/', 'BA00008424BA00008425BA00008426')
);
```

If all segments start with `BA`, then split on the position just before that.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QZSIn))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/\d+\K(?=BA)/', 'BA00008424BA00008425BA00008426')
);
```

The regex engine can traverse the string faster if it is told to greedily match sequences of one or more digits.  Then just before matching the lookahead, forget the previously matches digits with `\K`.

`preg_match_all()` is another one-call technique, but it unhelpfully generates a 2d array, while `preg_split()` more directly creates the desired 1d array.